# update XML file from dataset

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am attempting to update an XML file from a data-set, the XML file will be used to update artwork in adobe illustrator. I am trying to append each of the nodes within the XML file from the data in the data-set. At the moment I am looping through the data-set and retrieving the data correctly using.

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    For Each DataRow As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows     
        Dim strDatasheet As String = DataRow("Dataset").ToString
        Dim strRev As String = DataRow("Rev").ToString
        Dim strName As String = DataRow("Name").ToString
        Dim strDesc As String = DataRow("Desc").ToString
        Dim strMarketing As String = DataRow("Marketing").ToString
        Dim strProject As String = DataRow("Project").ToString

        Dim sampleDataSets As XElement = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "sampleDataSets").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim ns_v As XNamespace = sampleDataSets.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("v")
        Dim sampleDataSet As List(Of XElement) = sampleDataSets.Elements(ns_v + "sampleDataSet").ToList()

        Dim dataset As XElement = sampleDataSet(0).Elements().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Dataset").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim ns_dataset As XNamespace = dataset.Name.Namespace
        dataset.Element(ns_dataset + "p").Value = strDatasheet

        Dim rev As XElement = sampleDataSet(0).Elements().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Rev").FirstOrDefault()
        rev.Element(ns_dataset + "p").Value = strRev

        Dim name As XElement = sampleDataSet(0).Elements().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Name").FirstOrDefault()
        name.Element(ns_dataset + "p").Value = strName

        Dim desc As XElement = sampleDataSet(0).Elements().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Desc").FirstOrDefault()
        desc.Element(ns_dataset + "p").Value = strDesc

        Dim marketing As XElement = sampleDataSet(0).Elements().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Marketing").FirstOrDefault()
        marketing.Element(ns_dataset + "p").Value = strMarketing

        Dim project As XElement = sampleDataSet(0).Elements().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Project").FirstOrDefault()
        project.Element(ns_dataset + "p").Value = strProject
    Next
```

however I am not really sure about how to update the xml file. would anyone be able to offer any direction on how to append the Dataset, Rev, Name, Desc, Marketing, and Project nodes of the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd" [
          <!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
          <!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
          <!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
          <!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
          <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
          <!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
        ]>
        <svg>
        <variableSets  xmlns="ns_vars;">
          <variableSet  varSetName="binding1" locked="none">
            <variables>
              <variable varName="Dataset" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;"></variable>
              <variable varName="Rev" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;"></variable>
              <variable varName="Name" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;"></variable>
              <variable varName="Desc" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;"></variable>
              <variable varName="Marketing" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;"></variable>
              <variable varName="Project" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;"></variable>
            </variables>
            <v:sampleDataSets  xmlns:v="http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
              <v:sampleDataSet dataSetName="HYX8YA00">
                 <Dataset>
                    <p>YXTX1A00</p>
                 </Dataset>
                 <Rev>
                    <p>A00</p>
                 </Rev>
                <Name>
                    <p>YXTX1</p>
                </Name>
                <Desc>
                    <p>LBL,COO,KS,ESPL,E5250 15181</p>
                </Desc>
                <Marketing>
                    <p>Latitude E5250 15181</p>
                </Marketing>
                <Project>
                <p>Houston 12</p>
                </Project> 
              </v:sampleDataSet> 
            </v:sampleDataSets>
          </variableSet>
        </variableSets>
        </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky with the namespaces.  See code below

```css
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim sampleDataSets As XElement = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "sampleDataSets").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim ns_v As XNamespace = sampleDataSets.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("v")

        Dim sampleDataSet As List(Of XElement) = sampleDataSets.Elements(ns_v + "sampleDataSet").ToList()
        Dim dataset As XElement = sampleDataSet(0).Elements().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Dataset").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim ns_dataset As XNamespace = dataset.Name.Namespace
        dataset.Element(ns_dataset + "p").Value = 123
    End Sub

End Module​
```

Comment: Hi jdweng thank you for taking a little time to help, I have updated my code and I passed the datasheet, rev, name etc variables into the value for each of the elements but this results in the elements with the xml file all being blank

Comment: ok worked this particular problem out, the dataset had blank rows in it so I changed the select query that fills the data table to ignore blank rows filled the datatable properly.......now how to work out how to update the <v:sampleDataSet dataSetName="HYX8YA00">

Comment: It is an atttribute (name="value") so use something like : Dim dataSetName As XAttribute = sampleDataSet(0).Attribute("dataSetName")